# ¿Por qué mi informacion de contacto PHP, siempre llega a "Correo no Deseado"?

Tags: php, javascript, html5, email

Hola amigos el problema es que los datos llegan a "Correo no Deseado"; según yo he escrito bien los parámetros para que no suceda esto, qué puedo hacer aquí les dejo parte mi código php, saludos y gracias por sus comentarios.

```
if ($_POST) {
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$email = $POST['email'];
$telefono = $POST['telefono'];
$mensaje = $POST['mensaje'];
//
$email_to = "contacto@destino.com";
$email_subject = "Contacto desde Pagina Web";
//
$headers = "From: $nombre <$email> \r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();

//
$email_message = "Detalles del formulario de contacto"."<br>";
$email_message .= "Nombre: " . $_POST['nombre'] . "<br>";
$email_message .= "e-mail: " . $_POST['email'] . "<br>";
$email_message .= "Teléfono: " . $_POST['telefono'] . "<br>";
$email_message .= "Mensaje: " . $_POST['mensaje'] . "<br>";

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
}
```

Comment: Los datos están bien, el problema es que cuando aparece una aplicación enviando correos desde su propio servidor, todos los clientes de correo (hotmail/outlook, gmail, yahoo...) se lo toman como no deseado porque no lo conocen. Puedes emplear como dirección que envía, una de gmail o puedes pagar por algún servicio que te ponga en una lista de "no spammers"

Comment: Puede parecer una tontería, pero yo he tenido algún caso similar por no incluir en el mensaje de salida la fecha y hora ... de eso hace años, igual ya no afecta , pero me ha venido a la cabeza al leer tu consulta

Comment: Como comenta jmaiques, si el header tiene valores incorrectos o no contiene valores, el cliente lo envia a la carpeta de "no deseado" (Junk e-mail)

Answer (score -1):

En el caso que comentas, una de las razones por la cual el cliente determina que el email que recibe lo envia a correo no deseado es generalmente porque el email que se recibe no tienen datos en el header o estos no son validos.

Como ejemplo este script que agrega los valores básicos en el header, usando [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

```
<?php
...
...
$to      = 'contacto@destino.com';
$subject = 'Contacto desde Pagina Web';

$email_message = 'Detalles del formulario de contacto'.'<br>';
$email_message .= 'Nombre: ' . $_POST['nombre'] . '<br>';
$email_message .= 'e-mail: ' . $_POST['email'] . "<br>";
$email_message .= 'Teléfono: ' . $_POST['telefono'] . "<br>";
$email_message .= 'Mensaje: ' . $_POST['mensaje'] . "<br>";

//HEADERS!
$headers = 'From: wtfchamp@wtfchamp.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: wtfchamp@wtfchamp.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $email_message, $headers);
...
?>
```

Asegura enviar valores correctos en el header.